# Android I cannot uncheck initial RadioButton

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I cannot uncheck initial radiobutton after setting default checked button.

### Problem situation :: XML Code

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/stateRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/attendanceRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="School"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/hometimeRadioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RadioGroup>
```

#### Problem situation :: Initial state -> Works well

[image]

#### Problem situation :: When I touch Home button......

[image]

I cannot understand why it happened. I already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505262/android-radiobutton-isnt-uncheck-with-initial-checked-state) from stackoverflow. But it is not helpful to me and also too old post.

### What I tried to solve

#### Removing 1 line in XML

I remove the line, `android:checkedButton="@+id/attendanceRadioButton"` I works well. (I mean never both buttons are clicked simultaneously) But there is no default checked button. So this is not what I want.

#### Adding codes in onCreateView()

I already add 2 lines in `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` But not helpful. (Actually these views are on Fragment.)

```
stateRadioGroup.clearCheck();
attendanceRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

Same results as above images.

### My Android studio System(Config)

Android Studio : 3.0.1 
Gradle : 4.1 
compileSdkVersion : 27 
minSdkVersion : 21 
targetSdkVersion : 23 
Running Device : LG V10, Android 7.0

==============

## I think I found real possible reason

I made new Project for solving this problem. I think **this problem has a relationship with Fragment**. But I don't know how to solve this. So, please help me :(

### In this situation, Upper situation is happened.

There is `MainActivity` and `RadioButtonFragment` and I will inflate Fragment in `RadioButtonFragment` from `MainActivity` like below codes.

#### activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Your Package Name">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:name="io.github.tyeolrik.testradiobutton.RadioButtonFragment"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentLayout, new RadioButtonFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

#### fragment_radio_button.xml

```
<!-- Of course there is ConstraintLayout which wraps RadioGroup -->
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/buttonGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="School" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Home" />
</RadioGroup>
```

#### RadioButtonFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radio_button, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

### Problem explain

It works well when I just make a RadioGroup and some RadioButtons in Activity. But, in that case, making RadioButtons in Fragment, two buttons checking problem is happened.

Is there any idea to solve this?

#### What I import.

Not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` But `android.app.Fragment`

In MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

In RadioButtonFragment.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
```

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin At first, when fragment is started, "School" Radio button is checked. Because, I don't want to make empty button. But the problem is, when I toggle "Home" button, "School" Button should be unchecked but it doesn't as you can see.

Comment: ok, you mean "School" radio button is default checked when app started?

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin Yes!

Comment: if so, you only need to add `android:checked="true"` in your radio button xml.,try below

Comment: @TyeolRik Hi! I am facing the same problem where the radio button is clicked automatically. I wonder did you find the solution?

Comment: @swiftlearneer Well.. Maybe I did. But I am sorry that that question was long time ago and also, I already retired from android. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, 
**remove** below code from your **onCreateView()** method

```
stateRadioGroup.clearCheck();
attendanceRadioButton.setChecked(true);
```

And **add** the following in your xml.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/stateRadioGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/attendanceRadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="School" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/hometimeRadioButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Home" />

            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to check?

Comment: "School" radio button is default checked in my xml.

Comment: Well... I write the code, ```android:checked="true"``` in RadioButton XML, But same as above images.

Comment: are you sure  to remove `stateRadioGroup.clearCheck();
attendanceRadioButton.setChecked(true);` in your `onCreateView()` method?

Comment: Yes, I didn't write it!! I am sure.

Comment: As you can see, [ImgurImage](https://i.imgur.com/5BBqMsx.png) there is absolutely nothing.

Comment: I did what you said but nothing changed.... [ImgurImage](https://i.imgur.com/anC41zJ.png) I added ```android:checked="true"``` in Radiobutton

Comment: ok, but radio buttons within RadioGroup should be only one checked but in your case it is different.

Comment: I agree! I cannot understand how radiobuttons are checked at the same time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167217/discussion-between-zarni-myo-sett-win-and-tyeolrik).

Comment: I print out logs by using ```Log.d("Check", String.valueOf(stateRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));``` it returns as only one button is checked. I think this is graphic bugs.....

Comment: If you don't mind, please see my edited question. I think I found the reason why this problem happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try not setting check attribute for radioButton. Instead, add this to your radioGroup

```
android:checkedButton="@+id/attendanceRadioButton"
```

Edit:

Also, you dont have to init your radioButtons, you can listen to it using your radioGroup

Comment: Your solution was in this link which I mentioned. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505262/android-radiobutton-isnt-uncheck-with-initial-checked-state) And also, Not working to me :(

Comment: How about try adding `android:checked="false"` on your buttons and remove them in the fragment to avoid anything that changes their value.

Comment: First trial :: add ```android:checkedButton="@+id/attendanceRadioButton"``` in RadioGroup
Not working!
Second trial :: add ```android:checkedButton="@+id/attendanceRadioButton"``` in RadioGroup,  ```android:checked="false"``` in both RadioButtons. Not working!

Comment: If you don't mind, please see my edited question. I think I found the reason why this problem happened.

Comment: Did you try to remove them from view declaration? Maybe a snippet is messing with its state. Try not to declare RadioButtons in your fragment

Comment: I am afraid that I can't remove RadioButton in Fragment. Because my "actually real" project needs fragment for better UI :(